# OpenGL ES: Pass single float to vertex shader?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, vertex-shader

I'm trying to pass a single float to my vertex shader so I can set gl_PointSize to be that float. However, it's not working and I think it's due to me using glVertexAttribPointer:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 1, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), GLsizei(MemoryLayout<Vertex>.size), BUFFER_OFFSET(2 * MemoryLayout<Float>.size))
```

I need the buffer offset since I'm also setting the position using glVertexAttribPointer before that using this:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), GLsizei(MemoryLayout<Vertex>.size), BUFFER_OFFSET(0))
```

This is my vertex structure:

```
struct Vertex {
  var x, y, size: Float
}
```

This is the vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 Position;
attribute float Size; // I tried vec4, no luck

void main(void) {
  gl_PointSize = Size;
  gl_Position = Position;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think the `glVertexAttribPointer` call is the culprit?

Comment: It has vertex in the name when I'm trying to transfer a float, and I can't think of what else could be causing the problem since another part afterward works fine using it

Comment: Well, _Vertex_ doesn't mean _Vector_. In the GL, a Vertex is just a set of _attributes_, where each attribute can be a scalar or a two to four dimensional vector, so your usage of a vertex attribute here is fine. Did you actually _enable_ vertex attrib array 1?

Comment: Yep, at the very start. Do I need to define it as a vec4 in the shader even though it isn't or something?

Comment: no, you don't. WHatever might be wrong with your code, it is not the parts you pasted.

Comment: How do you know that the `Size` attribute is at location 1?

Comment: Doesn't glVertexAttribPointer set it to be that?

Comment: No, it sets up the attribute at index 1. But you don't know that `Size` is at index 1, unless you set it that way, for example by calling `glBindAttribLocation()` before linking the shader program.

Comment: Ah, okay. It's just strange since it seems to work fine unless I use something other than a vec4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reto Koradi had the answer! You need to call glBindAttribLocation beforehand when compiling the shader to bind it correctly.